# SumAsync retornar zero

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma consulta em `LINQ` onde uso o `SumAsync`, no entanto quando minha entidade está vazia tenho a exceção:

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

A consulta que estou tentando fazer é a seguinte

```
var valor = await db.Exemplos.SumAsync(a => a.Valor);
```

Como posso contornar isso e fazer o `SumAsync` retornar 0 caso a minha entidade não tenho dados ainda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que o `Sum` está sendo chamado num `IQueryable` e isso faz com que a execução deste método seja delegada para o *provider* do `Queryable`, ou seja — como você já deve imaginar, quem executa o `Sum`, na verdade, é o SQL Server. Você pode conferir este comportamento no [código fonte no *referencesource*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,1155).

O erro estoura justamente porque o SQL Server retorna `NULL` ao tentar executar um `SUM` numa "coleção vazia".

Você pode fazer o cast de **`a.Valor`** para **`decimal?`** ([*nullable decimal*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)) e usar o operador [*coalesce*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) no resultado final.

```
var valor = await db.Exemplos.SumAsync(a => (decimal?) a.Valor) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Mas será algum tipo de limitação da função SumAsync que ela já não trata esse tipo de situação?

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Editei a resposta pra contemplar isso

Comment: Mas se eu fizer `db.Exemplos.Sum(a => a.Valor)`, teria que fazer o cast como no SumAsync?

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Com certeza. O método ser assíncrono ou não não deve fazer diferença no comportamento.